# VkLayer_param_checker.dll Access Violation

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have a Vulkan 1.0.5.0 program set up, using the LunarG installer, and it works without enabling any layers.

When I try and enable either of:

```
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_param_checker
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation
```

I get an access violation in VkLayer_param_checker.dll or VkLayer_api_dump.dll when I try to call vkCreateInstance.

They also fail if I try and load any one individually as the only layer.

The JSON files are present in the registry under ExplicitLayers, and the files themselves looks fine.

I also get the message in visual studio that the dlls are loaded.

These layers worked on an older 1.0.3.1 test program, which is odd, and I'm able to enable all of the following:

```
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_device_limits
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_draw_state
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_image
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_mem_tracker
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_screenshot
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_swapchain
VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading
VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_unique_objects
VK_LAYER_VALVE_steam_overlay
```

Is there a specific order the layers must be loaded in? I'm sure I read that somewhere but I can't find it again. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Theres a few things I can suggest so I will add them as different comments: 1) When I was watching a tutorial on this, I got the impression that it does need to be in a particular order because they work up the stack. I could be wrong though.

Comment: 2) Try outputting the list of layers out to a command line or something, make sure they are in the same order as that, that will at least rule that possibility out.

Comment: 3) I am pretty sure standard validation just turns everything on, is it possible that you can't have standard validation on as well as other things? or maybe standard validation needs to go first. I will investigate this when I get home if you haven't by then :)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. If I query available layers they come out in the order above (minus the misbehaving ones). So that was the order I added them to the `ppLayersEnabled` member of the struct. If standard validation indeed enables all of them, it would explain why its crashing as it will be enabling both the ones that are failing. I did try just standard validation and it still crashes, in fact I tried all the failing ones above alone one at a time, and they still crash.

Comment: I will have a look at my validation code when I get back. It might be useful if you could show your code, but I can't quite remember what piece of code would be useful to see until I get back home.

Comment: I thought about adding the code, but I wasn't sure how it would be relevant. Plus it's pretty extensive as you are probably aware :)

Comment: Yeah, it is very extensive. As I said I don't really know what code would be useful to see because it is so big and I am not 100% familiar with it yet. I really need to check my code in so I can see it at work...

Comment: OK I have looked at my code and think I have a better idea of what is going on (Maybe). When you are adding layers are you adding it to the instance or the device (or both). Also are they the only layers you are adding. When you add a layer to the device it needs to have the same layer in the instancelayers. Although you probably already know that I just thought it might be useful to mention.

Comment: I was unable to get an access validation in the VkLayer_param_checker.dll or the VkLayer_api_dump.dll so I suspect that the last comment may not be useful, but when I got an access validation by adding it to my device to see if that's the cause the access validation, the program broke on vkCreateDevice. Could you tell me what call yours broke on, and also the preceding code around that, so if its the create device then whats your create device info, and probably anything to do with the physical device that you have done before that.

Comment: One other thing, is that I found somewhere which said that the explicit layers need to be activated through an environment variable or something. I didn't need to do this, but it could be environmental

Comment: From what I read, you can make layers available through the registry which does the same job, this must work as some other layers which I made available in the registry don't crash. I also have the layer set on for both the instance and device, but that doesn't matter as I can't get to the point where I call vkCreateDevice. It crashes on the call to vkCreateInstance.

Comment: You should be able to activate a layer on the instance but not the device IIRC. As you said though, not the other way around, i.e. you must have a layer on the instance if you have it on the device. Either way this is still not working and actually crashing in more places with the layers that worked previously. :( I'm going to try and reinstall the LunarG SDK again from scratch. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Strange that it won't allow you to create the instance. I think reinstalling the SDK may be the best from what you have said. I mean I am no expert but I don't think that you can really have that many variations on the create instance info. Let me know how it goes. Good Luck!

Comment: Just thought I would warn you that the param_checker has now been changed to LUNARG_parameter_validation in the latest version 1.0.8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108624/discussion-between-finlaybob-and-keithin8a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. And I'm slightly embarrassed to admit that it's an uninitialised variable.

After I moved to Vulkan 1.0.8 and I could find and load the correct VkLayer_parameter_validation.dll which had been built in debug.

The issue is that in my application info I had failed to assign pEngineName. Even assigning `""` would have worked. However I didn't assign anything. Given it's an unassigned `const char*`, it instantly transports us to undefined behaviour land. Vulkan must not be assigning it to `nullptr` either, otherwise the layer would have flagged it as such and actually given me that output. (But I'm not blaming it on that)

Technically I could have avoided this. It's my own fault for assuming it would be null or just `""`. I'm sure I also read somewhere that you had to make sure everything was assigned to in all the Vulkan structs.

I hope this may prevent people from making this same mistake, or if you have anything similar and come across this question that it will encourage you to CHECK YOUR VARIABLES!